# Is there a close form for $g(a,b,n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{ak+b}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, factorial, egyptian-fractions

We can be sure, that for $a>0$, $b>0$
$$f(a,b,n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{(-1)^k}{ak+b}=\frac{(an)!^{(a)}}{(an+b)!^{(a)}}$$
where $(an+b)!^{(a)}$ denotes multifactorial: $(n)!^{(1)}=n!$, $(2n)!^{(2)}=(2n)!!$, etc.

But if we make a little change
$$g(a,b,n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{ak+b}$$
we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+2}=\frac{n2^{n+1}+1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$
in general
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+2c}=\frac{n(2c-1)!}{n^{\overline {2c+1}}}\left(1+2^{n+1}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{c}\frac{n^{\overline {2m-1}}}{(2m-1)!}\right)$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+2c-1}=\frac{n(2c-2)!}{n^{\overline {2c}}}\left(-1+2^{n+1}\sum\limits_{m=1}^{c}\frac{n^{\overline {2m-2}}}{(2m-2)!}\right)$$
Is there a close form for $g(a,b,n)$?

Comment: It leads to a hypergeometric series

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, so there is nothing simple?

Comment: I think no, but i must longer working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start by  trying to prove the  first closed form given to  see if a
pattern does emerge. We use with $c$ a positive integer

$${n+c\choose n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k+c}$$

Now

$${n+c\choose n} {n\choose k}
= \frac{(n+c)!}{ (c)! \times k! \times (n-k)!}
= {n+c\choose k+c} {k+c\choose k}.$$

Hence we have for the sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n+c\choose k+c} {k+c\choose k} \frac{1}{k+c}
= \frac{1}{c}
\sum_{k=0}^n {n+c\choose k+c} {k+c-1\choose c-1}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{c}
\sum_{k=0}^n {k+c-1\choose c-1}  [z^{n-k}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+c+1}}
= \frac{1}{c}
\sum_{k=0}^n {k+c-1\choose c-1}  [z^{n}] z^k \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k+c+1}}.$$

Here we get no contribution to $[z^n]$ when $k\gt n$ so we may continue 
with

$$\frac{1}{c} [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{c+1}}
\sum_{k\ge 0} {k+c-1\choose c-1} z^k \frac{1}{(1-z)^{k}}
\\ = \frac{1}{c} [z^n] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{c+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1-z))^c}
\\ = \frac{1}{c} [z^n] \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^c}.$$

This is

$$\frac{1}{c} \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^c}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c 2^c} 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{z-1}
\frac{1}{(z-1/2)^c}.$$

With residues summing to zero we can evaluate this using the residues
at $z=1$, $z=1/2$ and $z=\infty.$ We get for $z=1$ the residue

$$\frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c}.$$

For the residue at infinity we find

$$- \frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c 2^c} 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} \frac{1}{(1/z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{1/z-1} \frac{1}{(1/z-1/2)^c}
\\ = - \frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c 2^c} 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} z^{n+1}
\frac{z}{1-z} \frac{z^c}{(1-z/2)^c}
\\ = - \frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c 2^c} 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}  z^{n+c}
\frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z/2)^c} = 0.$$

This also follows by inspection. The residue at $z=1/2$ requires
the use of Leibniz' rule as in

$$\frac{1}{p!} \left( \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{z-1} \right)^{(p)}
= \frac{1}{p!} \sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q} 
\frac{(-1)^q (n+q)!}{n! z^{n+1+q}}
(-1)^{p-q} \frac{(p-q)!}{(z-1)^{p-q+1}}
\\ = (-1)^p \sum_{q=0}^p {n+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{z^{n+1+q}} \frac{1}{(z-1)^{p-q+1}}.$$

We set $p=c-1$ and $z=1/2$ and restore the factor in front to get
for the residue

$$\frac{(-1)^{c+1}}{c 2^c} 
(-1)^{c-1} \sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{(1/2)^{n+1+q}} \frac{(-1)^{c-q}}{(1/2)^{c-q}}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^c 2^{n+1}}{c} 
\sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q.$$

Collecting everything we thus obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k+c}
= {n+c\choose c}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^c}{c}
\left(1-2^{n+1} \sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q\right).}$$

This is an  improvement in the sense  that if $n$ is  the variable and
$c$  is the  constant  then we  have  replaced the  sum  in $n$  terms
(variable) by a sum in $c$ terms (fixed) of polynomials in $n.$ We can
make this more explicit by writing

$$\sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^{c-1} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} 
\sum_{p=0}^q n^p {q+1\brack p+1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{c-1} n^p 
\sum_{q=p}^{c-1} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} {q+1\brack p+1}.$$

We find

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} \frac{1}{k+c}
= {n+c\choose c}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^c}{c}
\left(1-2^{n+1} \sum_{p=0}^{c-1} n^p 
\sum_{q=p}^{c-1} \frac{(-1)^q}{q!} {q+1\brack p+1}\right).}$$

With this last result we obtain closed forms for fixed $c$, e.g.
for $c=5$ it yields

$$\frac{-24+2^{n+1} (n^4+6n^3+23n^2+18n+24)}
{(n+5)\times\cdots\times (n+1)}.$$

**Addendum.** With the purpose of matching conjectures by OP
we write

$$\sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q
= \sum_{q=0}^{c-1} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q 
[z^{c-1}] \frac{z^q}{1-z}
\\ = [z^{c-1}] \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n+q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q
= [z^{c-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1+z)^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{c-1} [z^{c-1}] \frac{1}{1+z} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}}
= (-1)^{c-1} [z^{c-1}] \frac{1}{1-z^2} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}}.$$

With $c=2d+1$ where $d\ge 0$ this becomes

$$[z^{2d}] \frac{1}{1-z^2} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}}
= \sum_{q=0}^d {2q+n-1\choose 2q}$$

and when $c=2d$ where $d\ge 1$ it becomes

$$- [z^{2d-1}] \frac{1}{1-z^2} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}}
= - \sum_{q=0}^{d-1} {2q+n\choose 2q+1}.$$

We thus obtain in the first case the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n+2d+1\choose 2d+1}^{-1} \frac{1}{2d+1}
\left(-1+2^{n+1} \sum_{q=0}^d {2q+n-1\choose 2q} \right)}$$

and in the second case

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n+2d\choose 2d}^{-1} \frac{1}{2d}
\left(1+2^{n+1} \sum_{q=0}^{d-1} {2q+n\choose 2q+1} \right).}$$

These two confirm the conjectures by OP.

Comment: I hope we understand each other right? It's beautiful, that in the world exists people like you. What is your motivation for answering?

Comment: Thank you for the kind remark. It is an agreeable way of spending time and provides an engaging mental game. I try to simplify mathematical ideas and notation so that they may be understood by the layman.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\Large\mrm{f}\pars{a,b,n} = {\large ?}.}$

\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{a,b,n} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over ak + b} =
{1 \over a}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\int_{0}^{1}t^{k + b/a - 1}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{1}t^{b/a - 1}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t}^{k}\,\dd t =
{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{1}t^{b/a - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{1 \over a}\,{\Gamma\pars{b/a}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{b/a + n + 1}}\,,\qquad\Re\pars{b \over a} > 0}
\end{align}

---

> $\ds{\Large\mrm{g}\pars{a,b,n} = {\large ?}.}$

In following the $\textsf{'above procedure'}$, I'll arrive to
\begin{align}
\mrm{g}\pars{a,b,n} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{1 \over ak + b} =
{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{1}t^{b/a - 1}\pars{1 + t}^{n}\,\dd t
\,\,\,\stackrel{t\ \mapsto\ 1- t}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over a}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{b/a - 1}\,\pars{2 - t}^{n}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
{2^{n} \over a}\int_{0}^{1}t^{1 - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{b/a - 1}
\,\pars{1 - {1 \over 2}\,t}^{n}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> which is related to the
>   [Euler Type Expression for the Hypergeometric Function $\ds{\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).

Namely,
\begin{align}
\mrm{g}\pars{a,b,n} & \equiv
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}{1 \over ak + b} =
{2^{n} \over a}\,\
\overbrace{\mrm{B}\pars{1,{b \over a}}}^{\ds{a \over b}}\
\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{-n,1;{b \over a} + 1;{1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{{2^{n} \over b}\,
\mbox{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{-n,1;{b \over a} + 1;{1 \over 2}}\,,\qquad
\Re\pars{b \over a} > 0}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{B}}$  is the
>   [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: Thank you for answer! What about $g(a,b,n)$?

Comment: @user514787 Done. Thanks.