# What is the finite sum of an alternating odd sequence with binomial coefficients: $ \ \sum_{k=0}^{j} \binom{j}{k} \ \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Do we have a nice expression for the following finite series?
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{j} \binom{j}{k} \ \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}.$$
Any help is really appreciated since I can skip the part concerning the partial sums.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2719320/514787

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{1}{2k+1} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} x^{k-1/2} \, dx, $$
so interchanging this integral with the sum,
$$ \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} (-1)^k \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2} x^{k-1/2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} \sum_{k=0}^j \binom{j}{k} (-x)^k \, dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} (1-x)^j \, dx. $$
This is a special case of the Beta-function, or we can write it as
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} (1-x)^j \, dx = \binom{j+1/2}{j}^{-1}, $$
which of course expands to
$$ \frac{j!}{(j+1/2)(j-1/2) \dotsm (5/2) (3/2)} = \frac{2^j j!}{(2j+1)!!}. $$

Comment: Nice solution! Can you help me with finding a book covering these materials?

Comment: Any book on special functions will discuss the Beta-function (Whittaker and Watson's *Modern Analysis* is a venerable example, but there are many others). [A=B](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html) is all about hypergeometric series identities, which include binomials as a special case. I'm not sure if those cover exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

An overkill. From the [Melzak's identity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07006) $$\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}\frac{f\left(y-k\right)}{k+x}=\frac{f\left(x+y\right)}{x\dbinom{j+x}{j}}$$ where $f$ is an algebraic polynomial up to degree $j$ and $x\neq-k$ we get, taking $f\left(y\right)\equiv1$ and $x=1/2$, that $$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{j}\dbinom{j}{k}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}}{k+1/2}=\color{red}{\dbinom{j+1/2}{j}^{-1}}$$